# Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Error converting data type varchar to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble with the following SIMPLE query:

```
INSERT INTO table (
     [Date],
     [Name], 
     [Weight],
     [Position],
     [Effective_Maturity],
     [Yield_to_Worst],
     [Modified_Duration],
     [OAD],
     [CTD],
     [OAC],
     [OAS],
     [Coupon],
     [Credit_Rating],
     [CUSIP],
     [Market_Value],
     [Principal],
     [Yield_to_Maturity]) 
     VALUES 
    ('6/28/2013','ISHARES BARCLAYS TIPS BOND FUND','100','0','8.647','0.0772','0.0772','3.8629','8.204','8.2040','1.112','9.034','1.543','AAA','TIPETF','1796461','178696')
     GO
```

I'm not sure which variable in my table cannot be converted to numeric and my knowledge of data types in MS SQL is lacking. However, I think most of these inputs correctly fit their respective data types. The table data types are:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You should use single quotes for varchar data only! The rest is without quotes....

Comment: Format your question so that it is obvious which values go into which columns.

Comment: For troubleshooting purposes at the very least, your query should list the columns in the same order that they appear in the table, and your values list should be arranged vertically too. Makes it a lot easier to eyeball.

Comment: datetime format is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000 
Market_value = 'TIPETF' probably wrong column.

your values should match the columns specified on the update statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You try to put 'TIPETF' string in [Market_Value] column, which is numeric.

Answer (score 4):

Your fields line up incorrectly: `'AAA'` looks like a credit rating, not like a CUSIP ([CUSIPs are nine characters long](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUSIP)).

It looks like you skipped a value, or added a field somewhere in the middle, or both:

```
 [Date] = '6/28/2013',
 [Name] = 'ISHARES BARCLAYS TIPS BOND FUND'
 [Weight] = '100',
 [Position] = '0',
 [Effective_Maturity] = '8.647',
 [Yield_to_Worst] = '0.0772',
 [Modified_Duration] = '0.0772',
 [OAD] = '3.8629',
 [CTD] = '8.204',
 [OAC] = '8.2040',
 [OAS] = '1.112',
 [Coupon] = '9.034',
 [Credit_Rating] = '1.543',
 [CUSIP] = 'AAA',                      -- <<<=== THIS IS NOT A VALID CUSIP
 [Market_Value] = 'TIPETF',
 [Principal] = '1796461',
 [Yield_to_Maturity] = '178696'
```

To fix this issue, make sure that your column names "line up" with the values that you are inserting into them.